# Minecraft jar not marked as executable

Tags: permissions, java, minecraft

I looked up several tutorials on how to install and they dont work. I do everything correctly but then i get this:

> The file
>   '/home/mike/Downloads/minecraft.jar'
>   is not marked as executable.  If this
>   was downloaded or copied from an
>   untrusted source, it may be dangerous
>   to run.  For more details, read about
>   the executable bit.

I run the minecraft.jar with the Sun java runtime 6 but it doesnt work:/. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It still doesn't work. The box "mark as executable" unchecks as I click it

Answer (score 29):

The important part is in your message:

> "**The file '/home/mike/Downloads/minecraft.jar' is not marked as
> executable**. If this was downloaded or copied from an untrusted
> source, it may be dangerous to run. For more details, read about the
> executable bit."

### Command line

The command:

```
sudo chmod +x /home/mike/Downloads/minecraft.jar
```

will make it executable. Be sure to read the 2nd part of the message: make sure you got it from a trusted source.

---

### GUI

If it is easier for you, you can also view the file with Nautilus and **richt click** it, open **Properties**, open the **Permissions** tab,  and tick the box that says:

`Execute: Allow executing file as a program`.

[image]

---

### Other

From a very reliable source I have been told you can also do:

```
java -jar /home/mike/Downloads/minecraft.jar
```

Comment: Alternatively, he should also be able to use: "java -jar /home/mike/Downloads/minecraft.jar"

Comment: I tried all suggestions except java command, nothing worked. Any other things to be considered?

Answer (score 0):

Right click the minecraft.jar hit properties then do execute file as a program. This works for me and for others. Most likely this should get your minecraft to work.