# OpenJDK not running .jar files

Tags: java, minecraft, openjdk, jar

I've downloaded the .jar file for Minecraft, and I installed OpenJDK 6 from the software center, and I tried with 7 as well, but it keeps throwing the message "The file '/home/hunter/Downloads/minecraft.jar' is not marked as executable.  If this was downloaded or copied from an untrusted source, it may be dangerous to run.  For more details, read about the executable bit." However, when I go into the properties to mark it as executable, as many people say to do, the box is not there.

Comment: Bear in mind that Minecraft says to use official Oracle Java, so you might want to look into installing standard Java http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Minecraft jar not marked as executable](http://askubuntu.com/questions/43181/minecraft-jar-not-marked-as-executable)

Comment: @Musher OpenJDK works better for me, and that isn't the issue anyway. Your duplicate is correct though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the file executable:-

Press CTRL+T to open a terminal.

Enter this command `chmod +x /home/hunter/Downloads/minecraft.jar`